# Saga Reclassify grid problem

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, sextante-qgis-plugin, reclassify

I am using Qgis 2.1 ver. 5f5cd4c (64 bit version on win7 64) OSGeo installed. I was trying to reclassify a DEM in EPSG:32614. I used the SAGA's Reclassify algorithm in the processing toolbox. I defined that I wanted to use a simple table, defined the table and that I wanted the reclassified grid saved to a tif file. I also wanted the resulted reclassified DEM to be opened after the algorithm finished the calculations. This is what I am repeatedly getting:

[image]

I tried to open a new project and load the resulting raster manually, but Qgis does not recognize it as a valid raster data source:

[image]

I was able to open the file and convert it to GeoTIFF in SAGA. I wonder if I am missing something in the reclassifying procedure, or something related with the format of the resulting raster. Thanks in advance for any advice.

PS. I was able to use r.reclass to do what I wanted. I also tested the saga reclasify algorithm in other two installations and I have the same problem.

Gerardo

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having some problems with QGIS 2.18.12 saving the results to a permanent file. It works with a temporary file. I reported it as a bug here: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17080#change-81836, but it seems it can't be reproduced.

Comment: The only solution is to reclasify the raster using r.reclass in the processing toolbox. check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121532/how-to-reclass-a-raster-with-reclassify-grid-values-in-qgis/121559#121559

Comment: Thanks. The SAGA Reclassify tool is more user friendly, but it seems there are still some bugs. I'll use only r.reclass.