# How to reclass a raster with reclassify grid values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, table

I'm new in QGIS and I'm trying to reclass a raster with reclassify grid values.
I want to reclassify by table, however fixed table has only 3 rows and I need some more, but button to add is not activated.

Do you have any idea about how add more rows?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE! What QGIS version are you using? I am using 2.6 and when I run the "Reclassify grid values" plugin from the **Processing Toolbox**, I can add more rows by clicking on the "..." button on the right of the option which is enabled.

Comment: Strange...try disabling the **Processing** plugin from _Plugins_ > _Manage and install Plugins..._, restart QGIS and enable the plugin again (ps: you can add comments underneath this question instead of posting it as an answer :) )

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. No it hasn't worked. The button is still disabled :-S

Answer (score 16):

First make sure that processing plugin is activated. Go to plugins/install and manage plugins and look for processing. Make sure it is activated. It should look like this:

[image]

You must have a Processing menu. Choose toolbox. In the toolbox, go to the bottom and choose advanced interface. I think you are trying to use SAGA reclassifying tool. I personally prefer the GRASS reclassify tool. In order to work with this tool you must create a text file with the classification rules. It must be like this:

[image]

Once you have the classification rules file save it as a txt file. If you are using Windows you can create this file with Notepad. Now type r.reclass in the filter box as shown in the image and choose `r.reclass`.

[image]

Once you select `r.reclass` you must see this dialog box:

[image]

You must choose the input raster, the file that contains the classification rules and also the output file. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this option gives me another problem. It says that output layer could not be open, althoug "GRASS seems to be correctly installed and configured".

Comment: Try to load the classified layer manually. That happens to me when I choose to "open the output file after running algorithm". I simply avoid this step and load tha later manually. Hope it helps

Comment: @GerardoJimenez thank you for this- worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 3):

Fast and Best way to reclassification Raster in Qgis 3.2, 3.4, 3.6 version:

1. From 'Processing toolbox', on "Raster terrain analysis"; open "Slope" and then fill up the required parameter (just provide your raster as 'Elevation layer' as input, 'Z factor' Default: 1, after that, you will get slope raster.
2. On "Raster analysis"; open "Reclassify by table" which Reclassifies a raster band by assigning new class values based on the ranges specified in a fixed table. And then fill up the required parameters.
   At first input your slope raster as 'Raster Layer', 
   on 'Reclassification table' fill up it like below screenshot picture:

[image: Reclassification table]

Open "Show advanced parameter" and on 'Output no data value' let it Default: -9999.0000,
on 'Range boundaries' select "min <= value < max" ,
on 'Use no data when no range matches' let it Default: no,
on 'Output data type' which Defines the format of the output raster file, select "Int32".
hit run to get the reclassified slope raster.

3. I have made a Processing model as workflow, which can Reclassify 5 GB of DTM Raster at just 30 seconds, to download and use it please open the link below:
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bl2N-BHoxApVkD_V8OmYCRR2olJOpUQy/view?usp=sharing