# Reclassifying raster analysis (like the one in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, reclassify

I am trying to reclassify raster (DEM) in QGIS. I know how it is done in ArcGIS (Spatial Analyst, reclassify option), but I would like to know how it is done in QGIS?.

The point of my exercise is to set all the values of elevation in DEM in the range from 1200-1600 meters as 1.

Comment: [This](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/how-to-perform-raster-reclassification-in-qgis) might be a helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

To realize classification on raster data, import the raster, righ clic in the layer name and go to "Style" section. 
- Select "Singleband pseudocolor"
- Select at the right the "Spectral" color with your favorites parameters 
- Clic on "Classify" and change classe in the white zone at the left
- Clic Ok

More datails on the process documentation in the Qgis documentation here :
=> https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/changing_symbology.html

I hope i help you...

Comment: If you want to reclasify  a raster you can follow this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121532/reclass-in-qgis/121559#121559

Comment: Sorry..my comment just help on style and not for reclass values...i was off topic.