# Extract specific altitude curve from raster

Tags: qgis, feature-extraction

Is there any way one can extract a specific curve from a raster DEM qith QGIS? I know I can extract all curves, specifying the desired altitude interval between curves. But I was interested in eextracting a specific curve (i.e., I'd like to state something like "I want to extract a curve or a polygon corresponding to the 200 m values in the raster".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by curve? not something I've come across but have you tried the raster calculator and create a mask "raster layer = 200"?

Comment: Do you mean contour lines? If so, you can use `r.contour.level` in the processing toolbox.

Comment: May be you want to reclasify your raster, if so look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121532/how-to-reclass-a-raster-with-reclassify-grid-values-in-qgis/121559#121559 . Once yuo have done this you can convert the resulting raster to a vector layer using raster /conversion/polygonize